# Error 29503. The SQL Server service failed to start

Tags: installation, sql-server-2005, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to install SQL 2005 onto a 2012 R2 server. The install is failing at the end when it is trying to start the database service. I have looked in the install logs and I'm getting the following error. I'm running 8 virtual processors on the virtual machine (8 Cores). I have tried the following with no hope (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/954835/en-us).

```
Error 29503. The SQL Server service failed to start. For more information, see the SQL Server Books Online topics, "How to: View SQL Server 2005 Setup Log Files" and "Starting SQL Server Manually."
The error is  (1067) The process terminated unexpectedly.
.
<Failure Type='Fatal' Error='1067'>
<EndFunc Name='LaunchFunction' Return='1067' GetLastError='203'>
CustomAction Do_sqlScript.3EA9D9BF_D9D2_4023_B2A7_9E2137B2FB1B returned actual error code 1603 (note this may not be 100% accurate if translation happened inside sandbox)
05/18/2015 14:56:41.705 [4924]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 396

05/18/2015 14:56:41.705 [4924]: Detailed info about C:\Windows\assembly\tmp\ZLY9X5T6\microsoft.sqlserver.batchparser.dll

05/18/2015 14:56:41.705 [4924]:     File attributes: 00000080

05/18/2015 14:56:41.736 [4924]:     Restart Manager Info: 1 entries

05/18/2015 14:56:41.736 [4924]:         App[0]: (4924) Windows Installer (msiserver), type = 3 

05/18/2015 14:56:41.736 [4924]:     Security info:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         Owner: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         Group: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         DACL information: 4 entries:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         ACE[0]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         ACE[1]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-32-544

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         ACE[2]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-5-32-545

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:         ACE[3]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-15-2-1

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 396

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]: Detailed info about C:\Windows\assembly\tmp\A85JO5X5\microsoft.sqlserver.mgdsqldumper.dll

05/18/2015 14:56:41.752 [4924]:     File attributes: 00000080

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:     Restart Manager Info: 1 entries

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         App[0]: (4924) Windows Installer (msiserver), type = 3 

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:     Security info:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         Owner: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         Group: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         DACL information: 4 entries:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         ACE[0]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         ACE[1]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-32-544

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         ACE[2]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-5-32-545

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:         ACE[3]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-15-2-1

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 396

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]: Detailed info about C:\Windows\assembly\tmp\575VYDJW\Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.BusinessLogicSupport.dll

05/18/2015 14:56:41.783 [4924]:     File attributes: 00000080

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:     Restart Manager Info: 1 entries

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         App[0]: (4924) Windows Installer (msiserver), type = 3 

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:     Security info:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         Owner: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         Group: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         DACL information: 4 entries:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         ACE[0]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         ACE[1]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-32-544

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         ACE[2]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-5-32-545

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:         ACE[3]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-15-2-1

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]: Assembly Install: Failing with hr=80070005 at RemoveDirectoryAndChildren, line 396

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]: Detailed info about C:\Windows\assembly\tmp\FUF1AB3P\Microsoft.SqlServer.Replication.dll

05/18/2015 14:56:41.814 [4924]:     File attributes: 00000080

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:     Restart Manager Info: 1 entries

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         App[0]: (4924) Windows Installer (msiserver), type = 3 

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:     Security info:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         Owner: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         Group: S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         DACL information: 4 entries:

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         ACE[0]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-18

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         ACE[1]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001f01ff, SID = S-1-5-32-544

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         ACE[2]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-5-32-545

05/18/2015 14:56:41.846 [4924]:         ACE[3]: Type = 0x00, Flags = 010, Mask = 001200a9, SID = S-1-15-2-1

MSI (s) (3C:20) [14:56:41:877]: Note: 1: 2265 2:  3: -2147287035 
MSI (s) (3C:20) [14:56:41:877]: User policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
MSI (s) (3C:20) [14:56:41:877]: Machine policy value 'DisableRollback' is 0
Action ended 14:56:41: InstallFinalize. Return value 3.
```

Comment: Installing a product that is going end of life in under a year on a modern OS? Good luck.. Don't think you are going to find much support.

Comment: One can only try, we don't normally run this version but have the need to test a legacy product.

Comment: Apply SQL 2005 SP4 and attempt to start the service.